# Javascript: Accessing nested methods

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm aware questions like these have been answered before but I couldn't find a solution I could relate my code to.

I'm currently using the mxGraph library to implement a drop-down menu attached to shapes, but I'd like to extend that functionality to be able to dynamically generate menu items based on what shape is used.

```
if (vertex.getStyle() === '') checkControlType().addMenuItem('Item 1', 'Item 1 Alert');

function checkControlType() {
    // Installs context menu
    graph.popupMenuHandler.factoryMethod = function(menu, cell, evt)
    {

        function addMenuItem(itemString, itemFunction) {
            menu.addItem(itemString, null, function()
            {
                alert(itemFunction);
            });
        }

    menu.addSeparator();

    var submenu1 = menu.addItem('Submenu 1', null, null);

    menu.addItem('Subitem 1', null, function()
    {
        alert('Subitem 1');
    }, submenu1);

    menu.addItem('Subitem 1', null, function()
    {
        alert('Subitem 2');
    }, submenu1);
};
}
```

How would I use access addMenuItem from the IF statement above to create a menu item based on arguments I pass into it? (I had to include the function under the graph...factoryMethod function as it inherits .addItem from menu)

Comment: You can't, because `checkControlType` doesn't return anything.

Comment: When I remove the function text around addMenuItem and call just checkControlType(), it runs fine with a menu item. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: This construction `checkControlType().addMenuItem()` provides, that `checkControlType()` returns an object which has `.addMenuItem` as a property ...